# PDF Form Button border change (Acrobat)

Tags: javascript, acrobat

Creating a PDF form in Acrobat X.  The form has various selections listed in a grid style, and my client would like when one of the selections is clicked on for a circle or square to be drawn around the selection.  I have tried various methods to get this to work, but I keep running into road blocks.  Here is where I am so far:

I have figured out that I can place a button on top of the text and set the border and fill of the button to clear, and have no text entered for the label.  This basically makes the button a completely transparent box on top of the text.

What I would like to do is:  when the transparent button is clicked, change the border color from transparent to black, thus creating a box around the word, and looking like the word is enclosed in the box.  In the event that I can get some guidance in how to do this, I would also like for if the button is clicked a second time for the black border to return to transparent (in case the initial click is done in error.)

I am assuming this will need to be done by utilizing the javascript functionality of the PDF and assigning it to a button action Mouse Up.  However, **I must admit ignorance on what the code would be to accomplish this**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I may get back to you on this, but a helpful resource is found at:

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/javascript/AcroJSGuide.pdf

This is Adobe's reference on PDF forms, and includes information on Javascript used in their form calculations.

On page 267 of this document is this:

**How can I hide an Acrobat form field based on the value of another?**
Use the display method of the Global object:

```
var title = this.getField("title");
if (this.getField("showTitle").value == "Off")
title.display = display.hidden;
else
title.display = display.visible;
```

Five lines of code that goes somewhere. Maybe in the "calculate" portion of a field.

Line 1:  Set a variable called "title" that represents the existing form field named "title"
Line 2:  Start "if" statement that queries the value of field called "showTitle"
Line 3:  If the value of showTitle is "Off", then set the field "title" to hidden
Line 4,5: Otherwise, default the display value of field "title" to visible

If the field called "title" here is a text box, you can put in some text that will be either hidden or visible. You could have a blank field with a border, maybe, to use as your hidden/visible border, if there is no fill color, I think.

The field "showTitle" can be a check box, where the value on check is "Off".

I hope this helps. I am trying this out myself right now.